# How to align content within a cell and its size

Tags: tables, overleaf

[image]

How can I adjust the size of the upper rows, align the text at the center in a multirow cell (e.g., the number "100" in the image), and insert two lines within a cell without exceeding the page boundaries?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 
           \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Size/Metrics/Methods}} &\textbf{Base Line 1} &\textbf{Base Line 2} &\textbf{Base Line 3} &\textbf{Base Line 4} &\textbf{Proposed ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO}\\ \hline 
 
\multirow{4}{4em}{100}
 & Reference 1 & 0.153& 0.203& 0.465& 0.239& 0.052
\\ 
 & Reference 2 & 0.362& 0.107& 0.121& 0.123& 0.023
\\ 
 & Reference 3 & 0.234& 0.234& 0.523& 0.127& 0.327
\\ 
 & Reference 4 & 0.321& 0.128& 0.237& 0.320& 0.016
\\ \hline
         
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe try \multirow{4}{4em}{\begin{center}100\end{center}}?

Comment: Or maybe \multirow{4}{4em}{\hspace{18pt}100}

Comment: It worked. Any idea about having two lines in over cell and resize upper row?

Comment: ^What's the code for that specific part?

Comment: @Nate Code that I provided earlier which outputs the result in image.

Comment: When you say "resize upper row" do you mean adding space/padding around the text?  For "two lines in over cell" I assume you mean a double underline under the bold text.

Comment: @Nate Yes, space/padding. And for two lines, I meant to wrap the long text within a cell.

Comment: I'm not sure about wrapping the long text but I might add a line break after Proposed (\textbf{Proposed\\ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO}) might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{llccccc}[vlines] \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Size/Metrics/Methods} & 
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=2pt]{\bfseries} Base Line 1 &Base Line 2 &Base Line 3 &Base Line 4 & \Block{}{Proposed\\ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO}\\ \hline 
 \Block{4-1}{100}
 & Reference 1 & 0.153& 0.203& 0.465& 0.239& 0.052
\\ 
 & Reference 2 & 0.362& 0.107& 0.121& 0.123& 0.023
\\ 
 & Reference 3 & 0.234& 0.234& 0.523& 0.127& 0.327
\\ 
 & Reference 4 & 0.321& 0.128& 0.237& 0.320& 0.016
\\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Answer (score -2):

I can't say it'll work for sure but I'd try:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline\
\vspace{6pt}
 
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Size/Metrics/Methods}} &\textbf{Base Line 1} &\textbf{Base Line 2} &\textbf{Base Line 3} &\textbf{Base Line 4} &\textbf{Proposed ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO}\\\
\vspace{6pt}

\hline
```

Comment: This seems speculative. Have you tested it? What happens to vertical rules when using `\vspace` within the `tabular`? Also, can you include an image of the output to show that this addresses the question?

Comment: ^Could you please leave my previous answer as is?  Deleting it cost me 20 reputation points I really need right now.  It's not nice to do that when it's been upvoted.

Comment: This is a Q&A, not a forum. The deleted post was not an answer to the question, but rather a comment. Can you provide a way to fix the issue that was requester has rather than echoing their use of a manual (negative space) solution?

Comment: ^I had not yet gotten the required 50 reputation to be able to comment, so I posted it as an answer.  Please be a little understanding and not such a stickler.

Comment: It takes time to settle in here (anywhere). Use that time to learn the ropes (how to format code in posts, how privileges work, how to write up good answers (and questions)... lots to do!